# Payment form differences between Commerce 3 and Commerce 4 in headless application

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, documentation

I'm in the process of migrating Craft Commerce 3 to 4.

I handle the payments forms with VueJS, and I've been struggling to understand why my paymentMethod body params were ignored after the migration.

I had to read Commerce’s code to understand that input's names had to change from `name='payementMethod'` to `` :name="`paymentForm[${gatewayName}][paymentMethod]`" `` as `getBodyParam()` calls use `getPaymentFormParamName()` as part of the key.

Anyway, where could I have found this information ? Did not found anything in the migration guide, nor the doc.

Did I missed it ?

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We touch on this in the upgrade guide, under the [Payment Forms](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/upgrading.html#payment-forms) section.

The examples provided are specific to Twig, because that is Craft’s singular, built-in template language—if you are assembling this form data in a client-side application, you would be responsible for replicating the output’s structure (as far as the nesting of variables in a `FormData` payload).

Check out the Ajax section on our [Controller Actions](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/controller-actions.html) page for more information about sending data to the back-end!